# Nodejs async with express server

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, asynchronous, oauth

I use the following code which **works** as expected. The code uses `open ID connect` to login user. Because I'm pretty new to node and express, it will be great if I can get some tips for the `async` usage- e.g. if I’m doing it and the **error handling** correctly.

The code is doing connect via oidc layer
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect
which does a user login according to client secret and client id, then the authorization server is calling to the `redirect` route of the application  and if everything is OK the user logged in to the system.

This is the **index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const logon = require('./logon');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

logon(app)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('process started');
  });
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port,
  () => console.log(`listening on port: ${port}`));
```

This is the l**ogon.js**

```
const { Issuer, Strategy } = require('openid-client');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const azpi = require('./azpi');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');


module.exports = async (app) => {

  let oSrv;
  const durl = `${process.env.srvurl}/.well-known/openid-configuration`;
  try {
    oSrv = await Issuer.discover(durl);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error occured', err);
    return;
  }

  app.get('/', prs(), passport.authenticate('oidc'));

  const oSrvCli = new oSrv.Client({
    client_id: process.env.ci,
    client_secret: process.env.cs,
    token_endpoint_auth_method: 'client_secret_basic',
  });

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    done(null, obj);
  });

  const cfg = {
    scope: 'openid',
    redirect_uri: process.env.ruri,
    response_type: 'code',
    response_mode: 'form_post',
  };

  const prs = () => (req, res, next) => {
    passport.use(
      'oidc',
      new Strategy({ oSrvCli , cfg }, (tokenset, done) => {
        const claims = tokenset.claims();
        const user = {
          name: claims.name,
          id: claims.sub,
          id_token: tokenset.id_token,
        };
        return done(null, user);
      }),
    );
    next();
  };
  app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false,
    }),
  );
  app.use(cookieParser('csec'));
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      name: 'zta-auth',
      secret: 'csect',
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.get('/redirect', async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('oidc', async (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Authentication failed: ${err}`);
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return res.send('no identity');
      }

      req.login(user, async (e) => {
        if (e) {
          console.log('not able to login', e);
          return next(e);
        }
        try {
          const url = await azpi.GetUsers(user.id_token);
          return res.redirect(url);
        } catch (er) {
          res.send(er.message);
        }
      });
    })(req, res, next);   
  });
};
```

Is my async code usage is okay?

Comment: The purpose of the async keyword is to be allowed to use the await keyword inside (it also has a side effect of making the return be a promise). As such, you only need to declare a function async when you want to use await. You have marked several functions (in the form of lambdas) as async when you do no awaiting inside them (you await inside a nested function, only the nested one needs to be marked async).

Answer (score 4):

### Comments

While the code is mostly simple to follow, it would be good to add comments to document what decisions you made. Even if you are the only one maintaining this code your future self might not remember what considerations you had in the past. At least document the input, output and purpose of functions. Some style guides call for comments to be in certain formats - e.g. [JSDoc in Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#jsdoc).

### Nesting Levels

The nesting levels gets a bit deep towards the end of logon.js- some might describe it a bit as “callback hell”. [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/) has some good tips for keeping code shallow- like naming anonymous functions so they can be moved out (also may allow for use in unit and/or feature tests), modularize (which is already done somewhat with logon.js), etc.

### Variable name format

It would be best to use consistent formatting of variable names. I have worked on a PHP codebase that makes quite extensive use of hungarian notation but I am not fond of it and I haven't seen it used very often with JavaScript code. I happened to recently see [this Stack Overflow question about Hungarian notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111933/1575353) and while it is marked as off-topic it does have many answers. The top voted answer contains a link to an article by Joel Spolsky, CEO and co-founder of Stack Overflow: [*Making Wrong Code Look Wrong*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). I know realize that much of the code throughout that codebase is “Systems Hungarian”.

It appears there are two variables named using Hungarian notation (i.e. `oSrv` and `oSrvCli`) while most all other variables are all lowercase or camelCase. There seems to be one other outlier: `durl`- which seems to be the discovery URL. One could name that as `discoveryURL`, or take the server URL/host name out of it and make it a real constant - e.g. `const DISCOVERY_PATH = '/.well-known/openid-configuration';` , which can be appended to `process.env.srvurl` when used.

### Async functions

As was mentioned in a comment, the `async` keyword has likely been applied to more functions that necessary. For example, only functions that contain the `await` keyword need to be declared as asynchronous- e.g. the function assigned to `module.exports`, the callback to `req.login()`).

### Error handling

> By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked.<sup>[1](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)</sup>

> ```
> passport.authenticate('oidc', async (err, user) => {
>     if (err) {
>         console.log(`Authentication failed: ${err}`);
>         return next(err);
>     }
> ```

This error handling seems fine. Would it be helpful to log the `user` object in the callback to the call to `passport.authenticate()`? If so, consider sanitizing any sensitive information that may be attached. You could also consider an error logging service.

It appears your code follows the *Custom Callback* option for [`passport.authenticate()`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/). The sample under that section **Custom Callback** checks for `err` and when it is anything other than `false`-y it will return `next(err)`

> If the built-in options are not sufficient for handling an authentication request, a custom callback can be provided to allow the application to handle success or failure.

> ```
> app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
>   passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
>     if (err) { return next(err); }
> ```

> If authentication failed, `user` will be set to false. If an exception occurred, `err` will be set. An optional `info` argument will be passed, containing additional details provided by the strategy's verify callback.

It may be useful for you to read other reviews about [nodeJS and passport](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnode.js%5d%20%20passport) as well as [nodeJS and error-handling](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.js+error-handling?tab=Votes). The posts below might also be helpful:

- [Express Passport (node.js) error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15711127/1575353)
- [How to show custom error messages using passport and express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35452844/1575353)

### Promisifying `passport.authenticate()`

[This Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42382498/1575353) might be interesting if you want to use `await` with the call to `passport.authenticate()`:

> I've been failing to get passport.authenticate to work at all inside of an async/await or promise pattern. Here is an example I feel should work, but it fails to execute passport.authenticate().

> ```
> const passport = require("passport");
> let user;
> try {
>    user = await __promisifiedPassportAuthentication();
>    console.log("You'll never have this ", user);
> } catch (err) {
>    throw err;
> }
> function __promisifiedPassportAuthentication() {
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>         console.log("I run");
>         passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
>              if (err) reject(err);
>              if (user) resolve(user);
>          });
>     });
> }
> ```

The [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383763/1575353) claims that the OP needed to invoke the function returned by the call to `passport.authenticate()` passing `req` and `res`, which likely need to get passed to `__promisifiedPassportAuthentication()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! regard the async after few successful calls, somethimes I got the following error `req.session["oidc:accounts.rvm.com"] is undefined` for the same user not sure why, any idea as I think its related to async usage but not sure.

Comment: i see the error in `})(req, res, next);  ` in the last statement , is it related to some aysnc issue, as the it happens once on every 5-10 successful run

Comment: Thanks for that passport hint, I'm using it twice could you please provide exapmle how should my code be adopted to use it like you mentiond ? it will be great

Comment: No need as I try it out now and I got the exact same error...any other idea?  thanks

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure because I honestly haven't used PassportJS myself. I am mostly reviewing the code and can attempt to come up with something but that isn't the point of this site.

Comment: While I don't expect you to accept the answer, please consider voting on itl. ["_The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any user with sufficient reputation does. Vote up answers that are helpful, and vote down answers that give poor advice._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: 1+ why you are saying" I don't expect you to accept the answer" ? im trying to implement your suggestions, what I miss is currenlty the error handling ,with my context could you please add it to your answer ?How do you think I can improve it? regard the logs I've added as you suggested

Comment: Im just waiting to provide feedback where I can user better error handling, please provide example for `best practice` ,where I miss the error handling etc,and i'll close the question with the bounty. thanks!

Comment: IDK if it is sufficient but I've added more to the error handling section

Comment: Thanks,I see the code you have added for the erorr handling, Im not sure that I understand what is the different to my code , I use: `      if (err) {
        console.log(`Authentication failed: ${err}`);
        return next(err);
      }`  I didnt really understand , please elborate

Comment: I give you the bounty, but please provide example in my contexts how should I use better exception handling, not general , if this was your code how would you do it better then my code.

Comment: It depends on what the requirements are. If you are actively watching the logs then the code would be sufficient. Otherwise if you need to be notified when an error occurs then you may need to look into an error logging service or mechanism that would notify you (e.g. via email, text, etc.)